# Program to shuffle the alphabet

Tags: python, encryption, shuffle

I need to write a program that shuffles the alphabet 3 times and it should be written into text each time. Having a bit of trouble.

```
def CipherHelperFunction(): 
    import random 
    myAlphabet ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?" 
    for i in range(3): 
        dst=''.join(random.shuffle(myAlphabet,len(src))) 
        print dst
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us, do you have a question? Can you show your efforts, SO is not a code writing service. The idea is you state your problem, input data, desired output data, your code and all errors

Comment: You could paste some code over here. Leave some code over here.

Comment: What is the nature of the trouble you are having? Do you have any code?

Comment: How do I add the code I already have?

Comment: [Edit] your post, then copy and paste your code here. Select it, and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    myAlphList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",",","'",";",".","?"]
    x = myAlphList
    random.shuffle(x)
    re

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    import random
    myAlphabet ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?"
    for i in range(3):
        dst=''.join(random.shuffle(myAlphabet,len(src)))
        print dst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.shuffle` will return `None` because it does not return the list but alters the list itself. So you first have to make a list out of your alphabet, change this list with `shuffle` and then operate on the list.

```
import random

def cipher_helper_function():
    my_alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?")
    for i in range(3):
        random.shuffle(my_alphabet)
        dst = ''.join(my_alphabet)
        print(dst)
```

Please notice that I changed the function and variable name according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm entering the wrong thing when testing the function, but it's telling me there's an error.  I need the alphabet to be shuffled 3 times.

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    import random
    myAlphabetList = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?"]
    for i in range(3):
        random.shuffle(my_alphabet)
        dst = ''.join(my_alphabet)
        print(dst)

Comment: You define `myAlphabetList` as a list with only one element which is the string with your whole alphabet. That is not what you want. Please have a look at my code. I transfer a string to a list where every character is an element of it.

Comment: import random

def CipherHelperFunction():
    from random import randint
    my_alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",",","'",";",".","?"]
    
def shuffle(list):
    for elem in list:
        swap_list_elem(list, list.index(elem), randint(0, len(list) - 1))
    print (my_alphabet)
def swap_list_elem(list, a, b):
    list[b], list[a] = list[a], list[b]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I ran the code I posted and it works for me. What happens when you use exactly my code?

Comment: It worked this time. I'm not sure what was happening before.

Comment: If you want you may tick my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to random your string, you can replace print to file write:

```
import random
src="abcdefghigk"
for i in range(3):
    dst=''.join(random.sample(src,len(src)))
    print dst
```

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    import random
    src="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?"
    for i in range(3):
        dst=''.join(random.sample(src,len(src)))
        print dst

Comment: Says there's an error. Can't figure out where.

Comment: print your error info

Comment: Syntax Error:         print dst: <string>, line 6, pos 17

Comment: this code is not working under python 3, if you using python3 , replace print to print(des). I can get the output correct.

Comment: It's **print(dst)**  in python 3. And if you got the answer, then please accept it as well ,thanks!

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    import random
    myAlphabet ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,';.?"
    for i in range(3):
        dst=''.join(random.shuffle(myAlphabet,len(myAlphabet)))
        print(dst)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply swap list elements of alphabet in a loop.

```
from random import randint
mini_alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

def shuffle(list):
    for elem in list:
        swap_list_elem(list, list.index(elem), randint(0, len(list) - 1))
    print(mini_alphabet)
def swap_list_elem(list, a, b):
    list[b], list[a] = list[a], list[b]

shuffle(mini_alphabet)
shuffle(mini_alphabet)
shuffle(mini_alphabet)
```

Comment: Using the entire alphabet?

Comment: def CipherHelperFunction():
    from random import randint
    my_alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ',', '"', ';', '.', '?']
    
def shuffle(list):
    for elem in list:
        swap_list_elem(list, list.index(elem), randint(0, len(list) - 1))
    print(my_alphabet)
def swap_list_elem(list, a, b):
    list[b], list[a] = list[a], list[b]
    
    shuffle(my_alphabet)
    shuffle(my_alphabet)
    shuffle(my_alphabet)

Comment: Error says "my_alphabet not defined"